# Hilt viewModel is not destroyed when Composable function is removed from the composition

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I have a case where I have multiple bottom sheet for one screen (more than 5) and each sheet content has their own viewModel provided by Hilt, something like this:

```
when(bottomSheetType){
        BottomSheetType.TYPE1 -> Screen1(hiltViewModel<Type1>())
        BottomSheetType.TYPE2 -> Screen2(hiltViewModel<Type1>())
        BottomSheetType.TYPE3 -> Screen3(hiltViewModel<Type1>())
}
```

The problem is that each viewModel is scoped to the lifecycle of parent Composable that is registered in NavHost (they are destroyed when parent Composable is removed from NavController stack). Is it possible to scope each viewModel individual to their Composable lifecycle?